# Extension of characters of abelian locally compact groups

Tags: gr.group-theory, rt.representation-theory

Let $G$ be an abelian locally compact group and $H$ be its closed subgroup. It is known from Pontryagin duality theory that every unitary character of $H$ can be extended to $G$. I think this is true for any character. Am I right? What is the reference?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you mean that every continuous homomorphism $H\to\mathbf{R}$ can be extended to a continuous homomorphism $G\to\mathbf{R}$, this is contained in Theorème 5 of [1] (the "unitary" version is when $\mathbf{R}$ is replaced twice by $\mathbf{R}/\mathbf{Z}$).

[1] J. Dixmier. 
*Quelques propriétés des groupes abéliens localement compacts.* 
Bull. Sci. Math. (2) 81 (1957) 38-48.

Comment: Yves shot first! :-)